# Attribute Error (returning None) in Python For Loop - Yahoo Finance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling, yahoo-finance

I am new to coding and am trying to scrape various yahoo finance details using BeautifulSoup.

I have a for loop which iterates through a number of stock tickers. Sometimes, it returns an Attribute Error, None. It does not occur on a specific stock. Sometimes it is the 5th stock, others its the 400th... This causes the code to stop.

How do I prevent this from happening and what kind of exception / error handling should I be using?

My Code is below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

df = pd.read_excel('ASX_Screen_Basic_Materials+Utilities+Energy+Industrials.xlsx')
n = 0
descriptions = []
names = []
sectors = []
industries = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
    url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BHP.AX/profile?p=BHP.AX'
    url = url.replace('BHP.AX',str(row['Ticker']))
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    description = soup.find('p',{'class': 'Mt(15px) Lh(1.6)'}).text
    descriptions.append(description)
    print(description)

    name = soup.find('h3', {'class': 'Fz(m) Mb(10px)'}).text
    names.append(name)
    print(name)

    sector = soup.find('p', {'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'}).find_all('span')[1].text
    sectors.append(sector)
    print(sector)

    industry = soup.find('p', {'class': 'D(ib) Va(t)'}).find_all('span')[3].text
    industries.append(industry)
    print(industry)
    n = n+1
    print(n)

descriptions_ouput = pd.DataFrame(descriptions)
print(descriptions_ouput)
writer = ExcelWriter('ASX_Screen_Basic_Materials+Utilities+Energy+Industrials_Descriptions_Export.xlsx')
descriptions_ouput.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

names_ouput = pd.DataFrame(names)
print(names_ouput)
writer = ExcelWriter('ASX_Screen_Basic_Materials+Utilities+Energy+Industrials_Names_Export.xlsx')
names_ouput.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

sectors_ouput = pd.DataFrame(sectors)
print(sectors_ouput)
writer = ExcelWriter('ASX_Screen_Basic_Materials+Utilities+Energy+Industrials_Sectors_Export.xlsx')
sectors_ouput.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()

industries_ouput = pd.DataFrame(industries)
print(industries_ouput)
writer = ExcelWriter('ASX_Screen_Basic_Materials+Utilities+Energy+Industrials_Industries_Export.xlsx')
industries_ouput.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

Comment: You don't provide a stack trace (*why not?*) so it is difficult to be explicit. Look in  a tutorial for advice on writing a `try...except` block.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it could be easier when using [yfinance](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/):

```
!pip install yfinance

import yfinance as yf

tickerData = yf.Ticker("BHP.AX")
tickerDf = tickerData.info
tickerDf
```